# Algorithm which suggests synonyms based on some term?

Tags: java, php, algorithms

Is there an algorithm which I can use in order to generate synonyms for some term (word) in respect of a spam. I am writing a simple spam filter.

For example, I set that the app must omit a word "viagra" and press a button which saves this term into a filter database. A script automatically creates synonyms of this word, such as: v.i.a.g.r.a, via_gra, via-gra, and similar. Or I filter a curse, and it generates all the tricks people use to have their curses appear in their comments.

Comment: So do you want to *detect* those "synonyms" or do you want to *generate* them?

Comment: @JoachimSauer To generate them. To create a list of them

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I wrote it. To make it easy for me to create words which will be filtered and ignored. I am writing a simple spam filter. Accent on simple

Comment: I don't really get it. If you want to write a spam filter you want to *detect* the words, not *generate* them.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Look. In admin panel I enter a word and a tool/script will generate synonyms which I will write into Filter database. Then another tool will use these filters to detect words. But first I need a tool which will help me generate words for Filtering. Not need for real-time detection.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of building a dictionary of aliases for the same noun, you could instead test if a given word is an alias of this noun.

You could use many algorithm for this, the simplest one being the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm. This algorithm computes the distance between two words, for instance a word in a mail and a word in a dictionary. For instance the distance between `viagra` and `vi.agra` is 1.

You could then define a threshold below which two words are assumed to be equal (for example, if the distance is lower than 30% of the size of the words). 
You could enhance the distance algorithm to give lower weights for special characters (like a dash or underscore).

Another algorithm worth looking is the [Damerau-Lenvenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) algorithm, which is used to detect spelling mistakes.

Comment: Any implemented libraries for Java or PHP? I do not need a miracle, just a mediocre filter.

Comment: I don't know if there are any existing lib already implemented on the net, but the two algorithms I mentionned are very basic. I implemented them once in under 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of pattern recognition! This is an extremely hard task to get right. Whatever algorithm you use, the spammers *will* subvert it and somehow push messages that people recognize, but your program doesn't. You recognize letter substitutions, they move to numbers. You generalize over all characters, they use images. You use OCR, they invent something different.

It may not look it, but this is actually very near the absolute center of what artificial intelligence is about. If you had an algorithm so good that it equals human recognition, you shouldn't be working as a developer - you should get a tenured professorship at Harvard. Seriously.

Comment: I do not need nothing so complicated. Just a basic thing as I just need to prevent most of people pushing their words into comments. I know I cannot fight pros nor I want to.

Comment: Harvard. Or Google.

Comment: @mouviciel, nah.  Genetic algorithms, if done right, have shown to even surpass human recognition (albeit not by much).  Granted, it may not be what he's looking for because it would definitely be slower, but just emphasizing that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

**The bad news: if you want a spam filter, looking up words is definitely a bad approach.**

For instance, you can have a perfectly valid and long message where at some point the word "fuck" is used. Likewise, you can have spam messages full of "valid" words.

**The good news: spam filtering is a pattern recognition classic.**

Just lookup "spam filter" and "classification" and you should get plenty of results. A good starting approach would be:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering